# using parenthesis gives error while declaring new Node

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, binary, binary-tree, nodes

```
struct Node{
int data;
bolum *right;
bolum *left;
bolum *up;
};

int main(){
Node *root;
root = new Node(5 , NULL , NULL);
}
```

This code gives this 2 errors:

> new initializer expression list treated as compound expression
>   [-fpermissive]
>
> no matching function for call to 'Node::Node(int)

How can i solve this problems?

Comment: `Node` doesn't have a constructor taking three parameters. It's not clear what you hoped `new Node(5, NULL, NULL)` would do. `root = new Node{5, NULL, NULL};` should work though (note braces instead of parentheses); this performs aggregate initialization.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik can i use constructors with struct type, sorry for my low knowledge

Comment: Yes you can. `struct` is merely a class whose members are public by default.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why you are trying to create an object that way.
Structs can have constructors too, but in your case, your data are public, which means you can initialize them from the main.

Anyway, if you want to use a constructor with some parameters you have to implement one. That's why you get those errors.

Example:

```
Node (int data2,Node * p1, Node *p2,Node * p3){
    data = data2;
    right = p1;
    left = p2;
    up = p3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Node *root;
root = new Node;
*root={5 , NULL , NULL,NULL};`

May be it will help

Answer (score 0):

Can also use the tidier initialization list in the new constructor:

```
Node (int data2,Node * p1, Node *p2,Node * p3): data(data2),right(p1),left(p2),up(p3){}
```